# Templatetag to post a list of cmsplugin-blog entries on home page

Tags: django, plugins, content-management-system, templatetag

I'm using cmsplugin-blog with Django-cms. I want to display a list of latest blog entries in a homepage (not hooked with the plugin). For that purpose I created a templatetag. I could get a set of entries but do not know how to render their titles. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

This is the code.

cmsplugin_blog_tags.py:

```
17 # blog post widget
18 @register.inclusion_tag('cmsplugin_blog/entry_list_1_snippet.html', takes_context=True)
19 def render_entries_widget(context, entry_num):
20     request = context["request"]
21     language = get_language_from_request(request)
22     kw = get_translation_filter_language(Entry, language)
23     
24     return {
25         'entries': Entry.published.filter(**kw)[0:entry_num],
26     }
```

entry_list_1_snippet.html:

```
 1 {% load i18n placeholder_tags cmsplugin_blog_tags simple_translation_tags %}
 2 
 ...
 3 <div id="featposts-widget-2" class="widget featposts">
 4   <div class="widget-wrap">
 5     <h3 class="widgettitle"><span><a href="/blog">{% trans "VFOSS Blog" %}</a></span></h3>
 6     <div class="cat-posts-widget textwidget">
 7 
 8       {% for entry in entries|annotate_with_translations %}
           # line 9 does not work. Probably no request.
 9         {% with entry|get_preferred_translation_from_request:request as title %}
           # no excerpt showed.
10         {% with entry.placeholders|choose_placeholder:"blog_excerpt" as excerpt %}
11
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by injecting a list into the context with templatetag and included other html for rendering the list.

the tag:

```
 # blog post widget
 20 @register.tag
 21 def get_latest_entries(parser, token):
 22   bits = token.contents.split()
 23   if len(bits) != 4:
 24     raise TemplateSyntaxError, "(cmsplugin_blog) get_latest_entries tag takes exactly 3 arguments)"
 25   if bits[2] != 'as':
 26     raise TemplateSyntaxError, "second argument to the get_latest_links tag must be 'as'"
 27   return LatestEntriesNode(bits[1], bits[3])
 28 
 29 class LatestEntriesNode(Node):
 30   def __init__(self, num, varname):
 31     self.num, self.varname = num, varname
 32 
 33   def render(self, context):
 34     request = context["request"]
 35     language = get_language_from_request(request)
 36     kw = get_translation_filter_language(Entry, language)
 37     context[self.varname] = Entry.published.filter(**kw)[:self.num]
 38     return ''
```

Placing the tag where the list should appear:

```
  14 {% block entries_widget %}
  15   {% get_latest_entries 3 as blog_entries %}
  16   {% if blog_entries %}
  17     {% include "cmsplugin_blog/widget_latest_entry_include.html" %}
  18   {% else %}
  19     <p>{% trans "No entries" %}</p>
  20   {% endif %}
  21 {% endblock %}
```